# How to compile CMake from its source codes?

Tags: cmake

I get the CMake source code (not binary) from here:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

And I need to make some changes on the source code and then compile it myself to get the binaries.

How can I do that please?
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/install.html

Comment: I do not want to install CMake, I want to change the source code and then compile the codes. The link you sent me is abot pre-compiled codes. How Can I compile the code?